# Chowdeshwari Devi's mantra shakti used by the king for daily rituals?

Tags: history, rituals, mantras, devi

From the [wiki article on Chowdeshwari_Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chowdeshwari_Temple):

> Hundreds of years ago, it is said, that there was a kingdom called Nandavara on the banks of the river Tunga in Karnataka near Raichur district, or another namesake village Nandavaram located in the Banaganapalle mandal of the Kurnool district of Andhra Pradesh. ***According to a legend the king of Nandavara was a Shakti Upasaka. With the help of Mantra Shakti, the king used to wake up at 4 'O' Clock in the morning, reach Kasi, bathe, in the holy Ganga and return to his Kingdom before dawn and offer worship to Devi at Nandavara.*** This was his daily practice. Maharani becoming suspicious of his absence and questioned the king. The king revealed everything in detail. She having made up her mind to test the king compelled him to take her also with him. The king reluctantly accepted. The next day, he took her to Kasi along with him. Rani had her monthly course during their stay at Kasi. This affected the king and he lost his Mantra Shakti. As he was unable to return to his kingdom as usual, the King became restless and worried.

I am interested in knowing which "Mantra Shakti" the king was using for his daily rituals as mentioned in above bold part of paragraph ?

Comment: I think its not a genuine story

Comment: But it's on Wikipedia, they won't add the story in the article If they won't have any solid reference. @Rakesh

Comment: Its temple story. Folk legend. So there are many mantras for Shakti we cant know which mantra he used unless its specified.

Comment: Hmm but it's mentioned that what is it used for, right ? Can't we find based on that ? @Rakesh

Comment: I dont think its possible

Answer (score 1):

**[*Siddhis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi)** (Sanskrit: सिद्धि siddhi; fulfillment, accomplishment) are spiritual, paranormal, supernatural, or otherwise magical powers, abilities, and attainments that are the products of spiritual advancement ***through sādhanās such as meditation and yoga.***

The King in question might have obtained the ***siddhi*** - [Prāpti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi#Eight_classical_siddhis):, **ability to be anywhere at will**.

Comment: Yeah a probable answer for sure. Your answer is a lead on relating/finding Shakta reference for the same.